# Complications saving HTML/PHP from Windows to Linux - newline solutions not working

Tags: php, html, linux, windows, newline

I've gone through nearly every solution I could find in regards to how to treat the newline issues associated with moving from Windows to Linux with a variety of programs yet I still receive server errors.

How I work now is that I have a guest machine in Virtualbox running CentOS. I avoided compatibility issues for a long time by simply running NetBeans in the guest; however, I run this on a laptop with limited memory and while CentOS runs fine for my purposes NetBeans slows to a crawl - I can only disable so many features before its stops being and IDE and becomes a glorified text-only editor. This prompted me to try to find a solution for the compatibility again.

I've tried dos2unix on CentOS with no avail. I've tried programs that can save in the appropriate format (NotePad++ for example) with no luck. I've tried NetBeans loading an existing file, reading that it will respect the existing newline. I've also tried the NetBeans plugin 'Show and Change Line Endings' - a very popular solution - and it still doesn't work (both loading & creating new files.) I uninstalled & reinstalled NetBeans and while PHP files will throw an error, a *new* HTML file will give me a "Forbidden" page and existing files will throw an error.

I'm pretty much at my wits end given that I cannot find any other compatibility issue aside from the newline, and any amount of searching produces only results regarding newline. I feel like I am missing something here, but even if I take an existing *working* file and just save it under Window's with the supposed solutions the file breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that files moved from Windows to CentOS inherited only permissions for root; using 'chmod' to change permissions to allow all users to read the file allowed the content to be used.

For example: sudo chmod 754 mypage.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand as much as you are having line ending issues causing errors.

In Coda2 (http://www.panic.com) for OS X, it will highlight different new line endings and correct them.

I believe Sublime (http://www.sublimetext.com/2), available for Windows and Linux, will do the same.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 did solve an 'end of line' problem; however, HTML pages still show up as "forbidden" and PHP files throw a server error. This is still for both new files and existing/working files.

Comment: When moving files from Windows, you will always encounter permission errors unless you move via FTP and set your permissions as part of the transfer. If you are copying from linux/unix to another linux environment you can request permission are persistant.

I'm glad SubLime Text 2 worked.